# Data augmentation from directory and oriented features with Keras

Tags: keras, data-augmentation

Let this, be a dataset labeling the head pose for each photo:

```
image_path, head_pose
---------------------
michael/01-right.png, right
donie/01-right.png, right
lea/01-left.png, left
jack/01-up.png, up
(...)
```

The dataset is too big to be load at once but a data frame containing the above information is manageable (ie, not loading the images). Using Keras, I was thinking of creating my own `DataGenerator` in order to load the images batch by batch.

Then using `ImageDataGenerator` I can augment each batch. But I'd like to know when a horizontal flip is done because I want to change the associated prediction. Like if the person was facing her left, the expected class should be right and left if the image is flipped.  Maybe [extending](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py) the `ImageDataGenerator` ?

What's the best way to handle that with Keras ?